# Why do Arabic text breaks into two lines sometimes?

Tags: css, google-chrome, arabic, custom-font

I have seen this weird issue multiple times. For some reason, on Chrome, Arabic text sometimes breaks into two lines in the middle of a word.
For example, this url:
http://aitnews.com/?p=168010

Here's how it looks on Chrome:
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

An here's how it's supposed to be (Firefox):
[image: Firefox Screenshot]

I have no idea why this is happening. I think it's solvable using `overflow` but I would like to know the reason if possible.

**Update:**
The issue seems to be related to `word-wrap: break-word;` in my css. Removing this line solved the issue. I'm still interested in knowing the reason however.

Comment: Can you also provide plain Arabic text we can copy & paste for testing?

Comment: that is what word-wrap does. perhaps chrome is seeing that word-wrap is needed.

Comment: Is this same issue described [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393178)?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That's exactly the issue. Here's a CodePen based on the same bug report. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvQPvm

Comment: I would **suppose** (I didn't check) it's a problem in the font's kerning table. You don't need to change `work-break`, also `letter-spacing` will fix it (if you do not set `normal` and you can accept `1px` space between each character) and it won't affect `word-break` rule. Well you may (I'm guessing again) also fix it adjusting `font-kerning` but it may be much harder (at least from my POV).

Comment: I think `letter-spacing` is not possible given that Arabic letters must be connected. I also don't want to remove `word-break` because there are some data coming from users that might have long words and break the layout. Can you explain how to adjust `font-kerning`? Demonstrating it in an answer would be great. We are already using custom fonts so this is doable.

Comment: @Louy I just tried but unfortunately advanced typographic styles in CSS are almost unsupported (or supported IMO badly) so `font-kerning` isn't viable. I played with other properties but I didn't find anything you can use to fix **only** this issue without also changing something else (primary breaking)...do not forget to post your own answer if you find the solution for this!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti well that's unfortunate. I'll see what I can do. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This CSS

```
.entry-tags li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Fixed the issue.